# Scala : How to convert a List[String] to List[List[String]]

Tags: regex, list, scala, for-loop, functional-programming

I have a scala list as

```
scala> c
res18: List[String] = List(123  asd, 234 zxc)
```

and i want something like this

```
List(List(123,  asd),List(234, zxc))
```

how can i achieve that ? I tried

```
scala> var t = for (x <- c) x.split("\t")
t: Unit = ()
```

how can i split each element pf my list by space and then assign the result as a list of lists?

Answer (score 7):

An alternative is to use `map`, what usually is more readable if you have only one step:

```
c.map(_.split(" ").toList)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `yield` keyword to return a list from `for` loop:

```
var result = for (x <- c) yield x.split(" ")
```

But this will result in `List[Array[String]], if you want to have inner`List`, use:

```
var result = for (x <- c) yield x.split(" ").toList
```

Comment: Or the equivalent desugared `c.map(_.split(" ").toList)`

Comment: @Thilo not really, this will result in single `List`, you would have to use `map` instead

Comment: can i convert it to a list of Seq ? basically I want to convert it to a dataframe